# Does 「わるいところ」also have the meaning of "negative aspect of X"

Tags: usage

Does 「わるいところ」　also have the meaning of "negative aspect"? This I heard from a Japanese friend. If not, how would one say "the negative aspect of X"?

Comment: It actually does!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, わるいところ could indeed mean "negative aspect." ところ literally means "place", and this can be broadly interpreted as an actual place, a point in time, a characteristic, etc.

Some other examples of ところ used in the broader sense:

> ドレスのシンプルなところが好きだ。
>
> I like the simplicity of the dress. (Characteristic)
>
> 彼は高慢なところがない。
>
> He has no pride. (Characteristic)
>
> 列車は出たところだ.
>
> The train just left. (Point in time)