# the meaning of ところ in this sentence

Tags: meaning

1. この店のお菓子はとても有名です。その理由として、昔ながらの製法で、伝統を守っている**ところ**があげられます。

Seeing this sentence, I am wondering if I can rephrase the second sentence as "その理由は、昔ながらの製法で、伝統を守っているからです" or "その理由としてあげられるのは、昔ながらの製法で伝統を守っているところです".

Also, I find myself not knowing exactly "ところ" means in this context.
Therefore, I searched some sentence containing the same phrase,

2. 石見国の魅力のひとつとして、海・山・川の３つの自然がすべて満喫できるところが挙げられる。
3. (この複合構造船体)長期に渡る航行中に発生するトラブルに対しても、外科手術的な即応が可能なところがあげられる。

if I replace ところ with という特徴 in the three sentences, it seems that their meanings don't change, so we can interpret this ところ as 特徴. Am I correct?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54010/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2968/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32687/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24236/9831

Answer (score 0):

This ところ means 点, "point" in English. You can replace ところ with 点 but I feel 特徴 is a bit unnatural, though it means the similar thing as 特徴. For example, それが彼のよい所(点)なんだ(That is his good point).